# How to rewrite from Raw SQL to LINQ?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, rawsql

I would like to replace my Raw SQL with LINQ. Here's my code:

MyController:

```
        using MyProject.Models;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web.Http;

        namespace MyProject.Controllers
        {
            public class MyController : ApiController
            {
                [HttpGet]
                public List<User> UserData()
                {
                    var selUserData = "SELECT * FROM mydb.User";

                    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        var userData = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<User>(selUserData).ToList();

                        return userData;                        
                    }
                }

                public class User
                {
                    public int Id { get; set; }
                    public string Username { get; set; }
                    public string Password { get; set; }
                }
            }
        }
```

Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=,mydb;uid=root;password=mypass" />
</connectionStrings>
```

ApplicationDBContext.cs:

```
    using MySql.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace MyProject.Models
    {
        [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
        public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "MyEntities") { }
        }
    }
```

I've been searching the web for some days trying to find a solution, but no luck. Should my code look like something like `var userData = ctx...` which is just adding a few lines of LINQ syntax or am I doing it all wrong? I read about LINQ not being fully compatible with MySQL. What would my code look like if I were using MSSQL and what would look like if I were using MySQL?

EDIT:

UserDAL.cs:

```
public class UserDAL
{
    public static List<User> UserData()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
        {                
            var userData = ctx.Users.ToList();

            return userData;
        }
    }
}
```

MyModel.Context.cs (autogenerated code):

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public SloRideEntities()
        : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Ride> Rides { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs (autogenerated code):

```
public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.Rides = new HashSet<Ride>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ride> Rides { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: LINQ is a language technology - if you mean "not fully compatible with MySQL" you do not talk about LINQ, but a LINQ provider.

Comment: By 'not fully compatible' I meant that additional packages are needed to put it to work.

Comment: Makes no sense either, because the ONLY package that is in .NET by standard is LINQ to Objects (against objects in memory). Entity Framework is also an external package.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `DbSet<User>` to you context class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "MyEntities") { }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then you write

```
var userData = ctx.Users.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming ApplicationDbContext is the class generated by Entity Framework T4 template based on your entity model (edmx file, database first approach) and you have included your mydb.User in the model - then your ApplicationDbContext class should have a property named User(s) which would be a collection of Users.
So you would have something like below

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
     return ctx.Users.ToList();                       
}
```

Comment: I get this error: _An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details._ Where's the LINQ query then?

Comment: It works now, but I had to create a new Entity Data Model with Db First approach. In the beginning I added my _ApplicationDbContext.cs_ manually. I expected something simplier like changing my Raw SQL with LINQ. Now the amount of code is the same, but with a bunch of new files. I prefered the Raw SQL which was simplier, paradoxically.

Comment: Using embedded SQL directly in your code is considered a bad practice, generally - for many reasons.
ORM has many benefits, consider, for example how your code will change if you add related entity, say a User has a Department.
If you insist on staying with raw sql, which is not recommended, at least move it to an appropriate layer in your application - it should be in DAL, in some repository, not in the controller

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Can you link me a good working .NET Application Architecture example or maybe some tutorial, so I can learn how to do a proper architecture and how to give proper names to files, classes, methods etc.?

Comment: Not sure I can point you to a short and concise tutorials, but i can recommend a couple of books. You don't have to read those from cover to cover, but I'll bet you'll want to, as it's a great read.
So, on coding standards, idioms, styling, and principles - Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship - http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882
On architecture for the enterprise - Microsoft .NET - Architecting Applications for the Enterprise - http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-NET-Architecting-Applications-Enterprise/dp/0735685355

Comment: My Db consists of two tables, User & Ride. An user can have n rides, while a ride can have only 1 user. When creating the model, I added both tables. When i try `var userData = ctx.Users.ToList();` instead of raw SQL, I get this error: _'Rides' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'_   I wonder why?

Comment: Please post code sample, are you sure you're not calling this code outside the using block for your context, it surely looks like this from error message. 
Also, please mark my post as answer if above suggestions helped you. Thanks

Comment: Added additional code on the top as you suggested. Please, check under _EDIT:_

Comment: Can you please also attach call stack of the exception, alongside with the message?

Comment: Not sure how this would help. Call stack: http://s11.postimg.org/8khuz8q1e/Call_Stack.jpg

Comment: Please, help me with this, so I can mark your post as answer.